# Matrix indices for creating sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, indices

I want to create a 4 by 4 sparse matrix A. I want assign values (e.g. 1) to following entries:

```
A(2,1), A(3,1), A(4,1)
A(2,2), A(3,2), A(4,2)
A(2,3), A(3,3), A(4,3)
A(2,4), A(3,4), A(4,4)
```

According to the [manual page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/constructing-sparse-matrices.html), I know that I should store the indices by row and column respectively. That is, for row indices,

```
r=[2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
```

Also, for column indices

```
c=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

Since I want to assign 1 to each of the entries, so I use

`value = ones(1,length(r))`

Then, my sparse matrix will be

```
Matrix = sparse(r,c,value,4,4)
```

**My problem is this:**

Indeed, I want to construct a square matrix of arbitrary dimension. Says, if it is a 10 by 10 matrix, then my column vector will be

```
[1,2,..., 10, 1,2, ..., 10, 1,...,10, 1,...10]
```

For row vector, it will be

```
[2,2,...,2,3,3,...,3,...,10, 10, ...,10]
```

I would like to ask if there is a quick way to build these column and row vector in an efficient manner? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without knowing where exactly you want your nonzero elements. Your example vectors are not at all clear.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Those nonzero elements are all 1s.

Comment: It looks like you want to create a dense `ones` matrix and store it as sparse.  Why?

Comment: Where your nonzero elements are, not what your nonzero elements are. You are asking us for a relationship between your row and column indices, this could be basically anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question aims to create vectors `c,r` in an easy way.

```
n = 4;

c = repmat(1:n,1,n-1);
r = reshape(repmat(2:n,n,1),1,[]);

Matrix = sparse(r,c,value,n,n);
```

This will create your specified vectors in general.

However as pointed out by others full sparse matrixes are not very efficient due to overhead. If I recall correctly a sparse matrix offers advantages if the density is lower than 25%. Having everything except the first row will result in slower performance.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. It is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can `sparse` a matrix after creating its full version.

```
A = (10,10);
A(1,:) = 0;
B = sparse(A);
```